# Как сделать одинаковую высоту EditText и Button?

Tags: android, android-layout

Как сделать одинаковую высоту `EditText` и `Button`?

У меня кнопка всегда чуть больше по высоте как бы не настроил.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="11"
        android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Введите слово"
        android:minHeight="48dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Перевести"
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это из-за внутренних отступов самих виджетов. Можете в телефоне в настройках разработчкиа поставить галку "Отображать границы элементов" и посмотреть сколько места занимает каждый виджет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба элемента имеют одинаковую высоту. Та линия, которую Вы принимаете за нижнюю границу `EditText` на самом деле ей не является. Эта линия – это индикатор того, находится ли курсор в `EditText` или нет.

В принципе, Вы ее можете убрать, добавив `EditText` атрибут:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Понял..спасибо.